# Can I use PostgreSQL's "Special Date/Time Inputs" with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

PostgreSQL supports several ["Special Date/Time Inputs"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-SPECIAL-TABLE), strings that it interprets upon execution. Eg, `'now'` means "current transaction's start time", and `'infinity'` means "later than all other timestamps".

ActiveRecord does not seem to understand these - eg, `SomeRecord.update!(updated_at: DateTime.current)` works, but `SomeRecord.update!(updated_at: 'now')` tries to execute the `UPDATE` query with a `NULL`.

These special strings do work in Rails fixtures, because they go straight to the database. But is there a way to use them with an instantiated model?

Comment: Note: I'm using ActiveRecord 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

You can set the value with raw_write_attribute(:updated_at, 'now')

Comment: Hmmm, that looked promising, but using 4.2.2, 1) it is a private method, and 2) if I call it anyway with `send` and the args, while it does change how the instance `inspect` value looks, `record.save` runs an empty transaction - no `UPDATE` query.

Comment: hmm it's public in 4.2.4 - so not sure why it would be private in 4.2.2 http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Write.html#method-i-raw_write_attribute   and you can call updated_at_will_change! to trigger the dirty tracking so the update occurs

Comment: It is private in 4.2.4 - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb#L77-L102 - however, `.send(:raw_write_attribute, :updated_at, 'now'` + `.updated_at_will_change!` + `.save` does work, at least for 4.2.4. I'd be nervous to rely on a private method though.

Comment: This method seems replaced with the private `#write_attribute_without_type_cast` in 5.2+

Answer (score 0):

## Use [`.update_column`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_column)

Eg, `some_record.update_column(:updated_at, 'now')`.

**Warning** - this [bypasses validations, callbacks, and normal setting of timestamps](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns); it just issues an immediate `UPDATE` query.

Despite that, ActiveRecord contributor [Sean Griffin said](https://twitter.com/sgrif/status/649395930052083712) "`update_column` is probably the best 'hacky' answer" and that special string values like this aren't really well-supported and maybe shouldn't be. (I think I agree - it would make validation really awkward, both for ActiveRecord and in your own models.)

### A compromise to get validations, etc

Given that this is a "direct to database" method, one possible compromise to avoid skipping validations and callbacks would be:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  record.updated_at = Time.current         # temporary value
  record.save!                             # with validations, etc
  record.update_column(:updated_at, 'now') # final value
end
```

### Caveats for the console

A couple of other caveats I noticed for doing this in the console:

- Inspecting the record afterwards, I saw 'now' as the value for `created_at`. Only after doing `some_record.reload` did I see the timestamp.
- Doing this repeatedly didn't seem to give a new timestamp. I think that's because 'now' is "current transaction's start time", and maybe each `rails console` session uses one transaction. If I started a new console, I got a new value for 'now'

Comment: I'd rather have a way to do this as part of the normal save operations, but I found this and wanted to document it.